# Combination question on forming a committee

Tags: permutations, combinations, education

A committee of 3 experts is to be selected out of a panel of 7 persons. 3 of them are engineers, 3 are managers, and 1 is both an engineer and manager. In how many ways can the committee be selected if it must have at least one engineer and one manager?

Comment: This is few enough that you can do it by hand if you don't have a better idea.  What have you tried?

Comment: ya, sorry for bothering you, i got it by seeing another ques. total ways = (1C1)(3C1)(3C1) + 2X(1C1)(3C2) + 2X(3C1)(3C2) = 33

Answer (score 2):

$$\text{Total ways}={1\choose 1}{3\choose 1}{3\choose 1} + 2\times{1\choose 1}{3\choose 2} + 2\times{3\choose 1}{3\choose 2} = 33$$

Comment: Please add it to the body as an edit what you have answered above to avoid any further downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The total number of ways is:

$\binom {3} {1} \binom {3} {1} \binom {1} {1} + 2 \times \binom {3} {2} \binom {1} {1} + 2 \times\binom {3} {2} \binom {3} {1} =9 + (2 \times 3) + (2 \times 9) = 9 + 6 + 18 = 33.$

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: Sure @Toby Mak. Let $E$ denote the set of Engineers, $M$ denote the set of managers and $B$ denote the set of persons which are both engineer as well as manager out of $7$ persons in the panel.Then one can choose $3$ persons of the given category in five different ways. $(1)$ $1$ from each set, $(2)$ $2$ from $E$ and $1$ from $M$,  $(3)$ $1$ from $E$ and $2$ from $M$, $(4)$ $2$ from $E$ and $1$ from $B$ and $(5)$ $2$ from $M$ and $1$ from $B.$

Answer (score 0):

There are ${7\choose 3}=35$ ways to form a committee in total.

There are $2$ ways to form unfavorable committes: all three unique engineers or managers.

Hence: $35-2=33$.